# Custom decorator for Pyramid views: View function is ignored?

Tags: python, decorator, pyramid, python-decorators

In my Pyramid code, I register a function several times for different routes and templates. So my app is displaying the same data in different formats/views:

```
class MyViews(object):
    @view_config(route_name='A', renderer='A')
    @view_config(route_name='B', renderer='B')
    @view_config(route_name='C', renderer='C')
    @view_config(route_name='D', renderer='D')
    def my_view(self):
        return results
```

This works fine, but because I have many of those cases following a certain schema, I wanted to simplify my code like this:

```
def entity_search_method(type_name):
    def decorator(fkt):
        fkt = view_config(route_name = A % type_name, ...)(fkt)
        fkt = view_config(route_name = B % type_name, ...)(fkt)
        fkt = view_config(route_name = C % type_name, ...)(fkt)
        fkt = view_config(route_name = D % type_name, ...)(fkt)
        return fkt
    return decorator
```

And then:

```
class MyViews(object):
    @entity_search_method('some_type')
    def my_view(self):
        return results
```

In my understanding, this should do exactly the same as calling the decorators directly. I don't even need to care about `functools.wrap` or something like that, because I don't even generate a new function myself. But Pyramid ignores the method. Any hint what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`view_config` and the underlying library to pick up these decorators `venusian` is somewhat tricky. I think what you're missing here is that you need to specify a `view_config(..., _depth=1)` to indicate to venusian that the decorator has been wrapped. The depth is an indicator of where the actual function you're decorating is (in stack frames) with respect to the usage of the `view_config` decorator.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. As I will probably do more of this stuff in the future: Can you point me to some documentation where I can understand exactly what's going on?

Comment: As far as view_config goes, it's documented in its API here http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/view.html#pyramid.view.view_config but is lacking narrative docs for extending/wrapping. It looks like venusian is also missing docs for depth. Just opened https://github.com/Pylons/venusian/issues/30 to hopefully fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't *apply* the decorators; call the return value of `view_config(), passing in the item to decorate:

```
def entity_search_method(type_name):
    def decorator(fkt):
        fkt = view_config(route_name = A % type_name, ...)(fkt)
        fkt = view_config(route_name = B % type_name, ...)(fkt)
        fkt = view_config(route_name = C % type_name, ...)(fkt)
        fkt = view_config(route_name = D % type_name, ...)(fkt)
        return fkt
    return decorator
```

The `@view_config(route_name='D', renderer='D')` syntax takes the return value of the expression and calls it with the next object (function or output of another decorator) defined below it in the source, with the return value replacing the object-to-decorate.

In other words, the following:

```
@some_expression
def some_function():
    pass
```

becomes:

```
def some_function():
    pass
some_function = some_expression(some_function)
```

but the Pyramid view decorators are themselves callables that return a decorator function.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question. You're right, but that's exactly what I'm doing in my code. I just made a mistake in copying and reducing the code. I apply the decorators but the method is still ignored.

Comment: What happens if you apply the same decorators *manually* on top of this decorator? So place them before the `@entity_search_method('some_type')` line?

Comment: It works fine. It also works, if I put my own on top of the others.

Comment: Are you using the exact same `view_config()` arguments as generated by the custom decorator? There is nothing in this code that would mean the decorators are not applied.

Comment: In my original decorator I use of course `type_name` to generate the parameters. For testing purposes I have hard coded exactly the same values as my manual solution. And it still does not work.
In my understanding, my code should do exactly the same as manual application of the decorators. So something very strang/stupid must be going on. But I don't get it!?

Comment: That is why I am asking you to test your hypothesis properly; it appears to me that the manual application is subtly different from the templated decorator arguments inside your custom decorator. The code certainly appears to apply the decorators correctly.